# Collision issue between bodies depending on the velocity of one

Tags: javascript, three.js, game-physics, cannon.js

I need to make a ball entering a tube with multiple tubes in my world. I created a tube by creating multiple box shapes that I then move and rotate to complete the tour of the tube. So far so good.

I'm now struggling with the collisions between these tubes and a ball( a body based on a single sphere shape). Depending on the velocity I apply to the ball, sometimes the ball just go through the tube like there is no body. If I apply a smaller velocity value, the collision works as expected.

I tried many fixes like raising the number of iterations of the solver, changing the step of the world, changing the different options of the contactMaterial but nothing seems to work. As I am fairly new to Cannon.js and physic engines in general, I'm wondering if I'm just missing a special configuration of my world or anything like that.

I created two quick gifs to show of the velocity impacts the collision based on the three_fps example:

- with a shootVelo at 10: http://giphy.com/gifs/l0HlCK3SS8cmIkmSQ
- with a shootVelo at 60: http://giphy.com/gifs/3oriOcjND1QinT5KP6

Any help is welcome ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Read more about the tunneling problem [here](http://www.stencyl.com/help/view/continuous-collision-detection/). Note that Cannon.js does *not* have Continuous Collision Detection (CCD), and therefore the possible fixes are:

- use a smaller time step,
- make the tube walls thicker, or
- keep the shootVelo small.

Answer (score 0):

I think it largely depends on what calculates collisions and how. I created a small game some time ago, and I had the same problem. Basically the solution was to add to the object's depth the current position difference of the moving object (so it considers an object as still and the other as moving).

This fixes collisions with very thin objects, and with fast sprites, if the sprite is fast (large position delta) then the thin object is considered as thick, if it's slow it remains thin.

It might be hard to explain, if you want to check out the code it's here.
https://github.com/Mc128k/SquaredBobble